# Проверить значение переменной на tmpl странице

Tags: html, golang, framework

Как правильно организовать проверку на значение на tmpl странице. Используется gin:
Пример tmpl страницы:

```
Текст1  {{if .Test = 1}} Выводим этот текст {{end}} Текст2
```

Вот в переменной Test которая передается странице сохранена цифра, как произвести сверку единица ли это? Потому, что так он ругается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{if eq .Test 1}} Выводим этот текст {{end}}
```

См. https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/:

> There is also a set of binary comparison operators defined as functions:
>
> ```
> eq
>     Returns the boolean truth of arg1 == arg2
> ne
>     Returns the boolean truth of arg1 != arg2
> lt
>     Returns the boolean truth of arg1 < arg2
> le
>     Returns the boolean truth of arg1 <= arg2
> gt
>     Returns the boolean truth of arg1 > arg2
> ge
>     Returns the boolean truth of arg1 >= arg2
> ```